# What is the best way get the symmetric difference between two sets in java?

Tags: java, collections, set

I'm wondering if there is a quick/clean way to get the symmetric difference between two sets ?

I have:

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>();
s1.add("a");
s1.add("b");
s1.add("c");

Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>();
s2.add("b");
```

I need something like:

```
Set<String> diff = Something.diff(s1, s2);
// diff would contain ["a", "c"]
```

---

Just to clarify I need the **symmetric** difference.

Comment: Quick&easy: You could write Set<String> diff = new HashSet<String>(s1); diff.removeAll(s2);

Comment: @polkageist: it will fail for S1={"a","b","c"},S2={"b","d"}. result should be {"a","c","d"}

Comment: If by "difference" (cf. https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Set_difference#Relative_complement) the OP meant symmetric difference, then you're right. However, you can get this as either (A - B) + (B - A), or (A + B) - (A cap B). I don't know any quicker way in java to implement that.

Comment: Java 8 and Java 11 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52268640/1216775

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use some functions from the [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library (which is really great, I strongly recommend it!):

```
Sets.difference(s1, s2);
Sets.symmetricDifference(s1, s2);
```

Javadocs for [difference()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-) and [symmetricDifference()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#symmetricDifference-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-)

`symmetricDifference()` does exactly [what you are asking for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), but `difference()` is also often helpful.

Both methods return a live view, but you can for example call `.immutableCopy()` on the resulting set to get a non-changing set. If you don't want a view, but need a set instance you can modify, call `.copyInto(s3)`. See [SetView](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.SetView.html) for these methods.

Comment: Having just read the javadoc for symetricDifference(), I'm a bit concerned about this statement "Results are undefined if set1 and set2 are sets based on different equivalence relations (as **HashSet**, TreeSet, and the keySet of an IdentityHashMap all are)." That makes it sound like the results are undefined for the OP's case (and the Sets.symmetricDifference() method seems not so useful.

Comment: @Gus The JavaDoc wants to say that the results are undefined, if you use the method with two different sets that use different equivalence relations, for example, computing the difference between a `HashSet` and a `TreeSet` may be problematic. Using the method with two `HashSet`s, or two `TreeSets`, etc. is fine.

Comment: @Gus Furthermore it is also fine if you use the method with a `HashSet` and a `TreeSet`, if the `compareTo()` method and the `equals()` method of the elements agree with each other (which is strongly recommended by their documentation). So only in special cases the method cannot guarantee that the difference is computed correctly, in most practical cases it will work fine.

Comment: I had the same concern about that ["results are undefined"](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#symmetricDifference(java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set)) statement. Thank you @PhilippWendler for clarifying this!

Answer (score 35):

You want the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

```
public static <T> Set<T> diff(final Set<? extends T> s1, final Set<? extends T> s2) {
    Set<T> symmetricDiff = new HashSet<T>(s1);
    symmetricDiff.addAll(s2);
    Set<T> tmp = new HashSet<T>(s1);
    tmp.retainAll(s2);
    symmetricDiff.removeAll(tmp);
    return symmetricDiff;
}
```

If you want a library, [Apache Commons CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction-java.lang.Iterable-java.lang.Iterable-) has

```
CollectionUtils.disjunction(s1, s2)
```

which returns a non-generic `Collection`.

and [Guava Sets](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release04/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#symmetricDifference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) has

```
Sets.symmetricDifference(s1, s2)
```

which returns an unmodifiable `Set` as a generic `Sets.SetView`.

Guava is a bit more modern, supporting generics, but either of these will work.

Comment: thanks, I was actually looking for a lib that does it for me, as this is what I've currently done

Comment: [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html) from [Apache Commons Collections v4+](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) support generics

Answer (score 9):

If you can use [Apache-Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/), you are looking for [`CollectionUtils.disjunction(Collection a, Collection b)`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#disjunction%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Collection%29). It returns the symmetric difference of both Collections.

If not, substract (`removeAll`) the intersection (`retainAll`) of both sets to the union of both (`addAll`):

```
Set<String> intersection = new HashSet<String>(set1);
intersection.retainAll(set2);

Set<String> difference = new HashSet<String>();
difference.addAll(set1);
difference.addAll(set2);
difference.removeAll(intersection);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Loop through one set and compare.**

It's only `O(n)` to loop through one of the sets.  Consider this code:

```
for (String key: oldSet) {
    if (newSet.contains(key))
        newSet.remove(key);
    else
        newSet.add(key);
}
```

And the `newSet` will now contain only the unique entries from both sets.  It's fast, because you only need to loop through the elements in one of the sets and you don't have to create sets unless you explicitly need a copy.

Comment: Note that this is `O(n)` for `HashSet` with no collision only. For TreeSets, all three operations `add(key)`, `contains(key)` and `remove(key)` would require searching the tree once, i.e. an additional `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        set1.add(1);
        set1.add(4);
        set1.add(7);
        set1.add(9);

        set2.add(2);
        set2.add(4);
        set2.add(5);
        set2.add(6);
        set2.add(7);

        symmetricSetDifference(set1, set2);
    }

    public static void symmetricSetDifference(Set<Integer>set1, Set<Integer>set2){
        //creating a new set
        Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet<Integer>(set1);
        newSet.removeAll(set2);
        set2.removeAll(set1);
        newSet.addAll(set2);
        System.out.println(newSet);
    }
```

}

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

### Java 8 Solution

We can write two utility methods (for java 8 and prior) in some class `SetUtils (say)` as:

```
public static <T> Set<T> symmetricDifferenceJava8(final Set<T> setOne, final Set<T> setTwo) {
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<>(setOne);
    setTwo.stream().filter(not(resultSet::add)).forEach(resultSet::remove);
    return result;
}

public static <T> Set<T> symmetricDifference(final Set<T> setOne, final Set<T> setTwo) {
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<T>(setOne);
    for (T element : setTwo) {
        if (!result.add(element)) {
            result.remove(element);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> t) {
    return t.negate();
}
```

The method `add` returns false if element already exists and method negate is used to negate the predicate.

### Java 11

We have a [Predicate#not](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate)) method for predicate in Java 11 and can use it as:

```
public static <T> Set<T> symmetricDifferenceJava11(final Set<T> setOne, final Set<T> setTwo) {
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<>(setOne);
    setTwo.stream().filter(Predicate.not(resultSet::add)).forEach(resultSet::remove);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
        set1.add(1);
        set1.add(4);
        set1.add(7);
        set1.add(9);

        set2.add(2);
        set2.add(4);
        set2.add(5);
        set2.add(6);
        set2.add(7);

        symmetricSetDifference(set1, set2);
    }

    public static void symmetricSetDifference(Set<Integer>set1, Set<Integer>set2){
        //creating a new set
        Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet<Integer>(set1);
        newSet.removeAll(set2);
        set2.removeAll(set1);
        newSet.addAll(set2);
        System.out.println(newSet);
    }
```

If `a` and `b` are sets

```
a - b
```

is everything in `a` that's not in `b`.

```
>>> a = {1,2,3}
>>> b = {1,4,5}
>>> 
>>> a - b
{2, 3}
>>> b - a
{4, 5}
```

`a.symmetric_difference(b)` are all the elements that are in exactly one set, e.g. the union of `a - b` and `b - a`.

```
>>> a.symmetric_difference(b)
{2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> (a - b).union(b - a)
{2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static <T> Set<T> symmetricDifference(Set<? extends T> a, Set<? extends T> b) {
    return Stream.of(a, b).flatMap(Collection::stream).filter(d -> !(a.contains(d) && b.contains(d)))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Your answer is not relevant to the question.  Your code is for ***difference*** the question is about ***symmetric difference***

Comment: @TomerBu corrected the answer.

Comment: Nice!
this was my implementation:

public static <T> Set<T> symmetricDifference(Set<? extends T> a, Set<? extends T> b) {

    //copy a values to resultSet
    Set<T> resultSet = new HashSet<>(a);

    //add all the items from b to resultSet and remember the ones that returned false (intersection)
    b.stream().filter(Predicate.not(resultSet::add)) //add b to resultSet and keep only the intersection
            .forEach(resultSet::remove);//remove the intersection from resultSet
    return resultSet;
}

but yours is nicer (one line :-)