# Getting the difference between two sets

Tags: java, set

So if I have two sets:

```
Set<Integer> test1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
test1.add(1);
test1.add(2);
test1.add(3);

Set<Integer> test2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
test2.add(1);
test2.add(2);
test2.add(3);
test2.add(4);
test2.add(5);
```

Is there a way to compare them and only have a set of 4 and 5 returned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064570/what-is-the-best-way-get-the-symmetric-difference-between-two-sets-in-java

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate: symmetric difference and difference are not the same.

Comment: If `test1` contained `6`, would the answer be 4,5,6? ie do you want  the symmetric difference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference

Comment: if test1 contained 6, I would want the answer to still be 4, 5.

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Try this

```
test2.removeAll(test1);
```

[Set#removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll)

> Removes from this set all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation). If the specified collection is also a set, this operation effectively modifies this set so that its value is the asymmetric set difference of the two sets.

Comment: This will work but I think it would be a nice feature to have the set operations like union , difference built in java. The above solution will modify the set , in many situations we don't really want that.

Comment: How can Java have the gall to call this data structure a `Set` when it doesn't define `union`, `intersection` or `difference`!!!

Comment: This solution is not fully correct.  Because the order of test1 and test2 makes a difference.

Comment: Would `test1.removeAll(test2);` return the same result as `test2.removeAll(test1);` ?

Comment: @datv The result would be different. `test1.removeAll(test2)` is an empty set. `test2.removeAll(test1)` is `{4, 5}`.

Comment: @BojanPetkovic This gives the elements of `test2` that are not present in `test1`, which is exactly what the OP is asking for.

Comment: This is extra useful combined with double braces: `new HashSet(set1) {{ removeAll(set2); }};`

Comment: The IDE gives a hint that "Call to 'set.removeAll(list)' may work slowly ", this can be replaced to `test1.forEach(test2::remove)`

Answer (score 154):

If you use Guava (former Google Collections) library there is a solution:

```
SetView<Number> difference = com.google.common.collect.Sets.difference(test2, test1);
```

The returned `SetView` is a `Set`, it is a live representation you can either make immutable or copy to another set. `test1` and `test2` are left intact.

Comment: Note that the [order](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference(java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set)) of test2 and test1 matters. There also is [symmetricDifference()](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#symmetricDifference(java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set)) where the order doesn't matter.

Comment: `symmetricDifference()` will bring all but the intersection, that's not what the original question asked for.

Answer (score 26):

You can use Apache Commons `CollectionUtils.disjunction` to get all differences, or `CollectionUtils.subtract` to get the difference in the first collection.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is an example of how to do that:

```java
import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import java.util.List;

var collection1 = List.of(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var collection2 = List.of(       1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

// [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
System.out.println(collection1);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
System.out.println(collection2);

// [-1, 0]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.subtract(collection1, collection2));
// [6, 7, 8, 9]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.subtract(collection2, collection1));

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.retainAll(collection1, collection2));
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.retainAll(collection2, collection1));

// [-1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.collate(collection1, collection2));
// [-1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.collate(collection2, collection1));

// [-1, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.disjunction(collection1, collection2));
// [-1, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.disjunction(collection2, collection1));

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.intersection(collection1, collection2));
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.intersection(collection2, collection1));

// [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.union(collection1, collection2));
// [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
System.out.println(CollectionUtils.union(collection2, collection1));
```

Comment: From which project does `CollectionUtils` come from? Does 1 have to assume that it's from Apache Commons Collection?

Comment: `SetUtils.difference(a,b)` is also another option.

Answer (score 21):

Yes:

```
test2.removeAll(test1)
```

Although this will mutate `test2`, so create a copy if you need to preserve it.

Also, you probably meant `<Integer>` instead of `<int>`.

Answer (score 21):

### Java 8

We can make use of [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) which takes a predicate to write a utility method as:

```
// computes the difference without modifying the sets
public static <T> Set<T> differenceJava8(final Set<T> setOne, final Set<T> setTwo) {
     Set<T> result = new HashSet<T>(setOne);
     result.removeIf(setTwo::contains);
     return result;
}
```

And in case we are still at some prior version then we can use removeAll as:

```
public static <T> Set<T> difference(final Set<T> setOne, final Set<T> setTwo) {
     Set<T> result = new HashSet<T>(setOne);
     result.removeAll(setTwo);
     return result;
}
```

Comment: works flawleslly!

Comment: Are there benefits of using `removeIf`?

Comment: @Winand The `removeIf` is useful when one needs to remove every elements matching a predicate. and `remove` is used to remove a single known element.

Comment: I think I asked about `removeIf` vs. `removeAll`

Answer (score 12):

Adding a solution which I've recently used myself and haven't seen mentioned here. If you have Apache Commons Collections available then you can use the `SetUtils#difference` method:

```
// Returns all the elements of test2 which are not in test1
SetUtils.difference(test2, test1)
```

Note that according to the documentation the returned set is an unmodifiable view:

> Returns a unmodifiable view containing the difference of the given Sets, denoted by a \ b (or a - b).
> The returned view contains all elements of a that are not a member of b.

Full documentation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/SetUtils.html#difference-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-

Answer (score 5):

Just to put one example here (system is in `existingState`, and we want to find elements to remove (elements that are not in `newState` but are present in `existingState`) and elements to add (elements that are in `newState` but are not present in `existingState`) :

```
public class AddAndRemove {

  static Set<Integer> existingState = Set.of(1,2,3,4,5);
  static Set<Integer> newState = Set.of(0,5,2,11,3,99);

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Integer> add = new HashSet<>(newState);
    add.removeAll(existingState);

    System.out.println("Elements to add : " + add);

    Set<Integer> remove = new HashSet<>(existingState);
    remove.removeAll(newState);

    System.out.println("Elements to remove : " + remove);

  }
}
```

would output this as a result:

```
Elements to add : [0, 99, 11]
Elements to remove : [1, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

The order is important, since you need 4 and 5 which is int (not Integer),
Use `test2.removeAll(test1)`.

Comment: Your answer is duplicate. This solution has already been presented.

Comment: Solution is same--i agree , but didnt wanted to miss the order of comparing the sets, which i mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, you could try something like this:

```
public Set<Number> difference(final Set<Number> set1, final Set<Number> set2){
    final Set<Number> larger = set1.size() > set2.size() ? set1 : set2;
    final Set<Number> smaller = larger.equals(set1) ? set2 : set1;
    return larger.stream().filter(n -> !smaller.contains(n)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Perhaps you have failed to realize that the other answers don't check to see which `Set` is larger... Therefore, if you are trying to subtract a a smaller `Set` from a larger `Set`, you will receive different results.

Comment: you are assuming that the consumer of that function always wants to subtract the smaller set. Set difference is anticommutative (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticommutativity). A-B != B-A

Comment: Regardless which variant of difference you implement, I would use `public static <T> Set<T> difference(final Set<T> set1, final Set<T> set2) {`as signature, the method is then usable as generic utility function.

Comment: @kap but then add a `Comparator<T>` to be able to customize the comparison because `equals` is not always enough.

Comment: This will lead to unexpected results as the order of the difference operation may be switched without the user being aware. Subtraction of a larger set from a smaller set is mathematically well-defined and there are plenty of use cases for it.

Comment: set difference is not a commutative operation. the order of the operands matters. The OP question and comments indicates that he wants to do test2 - test1. your answer is missleading... at least if it were the symetric difference, but it isn't

Comment: This is very misleading. I can imagine this working if the smaller set only contained items in the larger set, but unfortunately that doesn't cover every use case. Gotta think outside the box. Set difference has nothing to do with the size, so you're just taking a difference and switching the order arbitrarily. I downvoted this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a union using .addAll(), and an intersection using .retainAll(), of the two sets and use .removeIf(), to remove the intersection (or the duplicated element) from the union.

```
HashSet union = new HashSet(group1);
union.addAll(group2);
        
System.out.println("Union: " + union);
        
HashSet intersection = new HashSet(group1);
intersection.retainAll(group2);
        
System.out.println("Intersection: " + intersection);
        
HashSet difference = new HashSet(union);
difference.removeIf(n -> (difference.contains(intersection)));
        
System.out.println("Difference: " + difference);
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaning on the answer by Bojan Vukasovic here is a more complete answer.

It actually returns a delta providing the list of elements added and remove.

The order you pass the sets to the delta method is important.

To obtain a delta:

```java
Set<Integer> test1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
test1.add(1);
test1.add(2);
test1.add(3);
test1.add(9);

Set<Integer> test2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
test2.add(1);
test2.add(2);
test2.add(3);
test2.add(4);
test2.add(5);

var delta = Sets.delta(test1, test2);

delta.additions.equals(Set.of(4,5));
delta.subtractions.equals(Set.of(9));
```

```java
package dev.onepub.util;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sets
{
    /**
     * Calculates the delta of the two sets.
     * 
     * The method assumes that you have an existing set
     * that has been revised.
     * 
     * The delta is expressed as:
     *  additions - the list of items FOUND in the revised set, that are not in the existing set.
     *  subtractions - the list of items NOT in the revised set, that are in the existing set.
     *  
     * The existing and revised sets are left unchanged.
     * 
     * @param <T>
     * @param existing - the original set used as the baseline 
     * @param revised - the revised set which will be compared against the existing set.
     * @return a SetDelta that describes the set of changes.
     */
    static public <T> SetDelta<T> delta(Set<T> existing, Set<T> revised)
    {
        var additions = new HashSet<>(revised);
        additions.removeAll(existing);

        var subtractions = new HashSet<>(existing);
        subtractions.removeAll(revised);

        return new SetDelta<T>(additions, subtractions);
    }
    
    /**
     * Describes the changes between two sets. 
     * @author bsutton
     *
     * @param <T> the type of entity held by the set.
     */
    static public class SetDelta<T>
    {
        public SetDelta(HashSet<T> additions, HashSet<T> subtractions)
        {
            this.additions = additions;
            this.subtractions = subtractions;
        }

        // The set of additional items
        final public Set<T> additions;
        
        // The set of removed items.
        final public Set<T> subtractions;

    }
}
```

And the unit tests

```java
package dev.onepub.util;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class SetsTest
{

    @Test
    void test()
    {
        Set<Integer> existingState = Set.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        Set<Integer> newState = Set.of(0, 5, 2, 11, 3, 99);

        var delta = Sets.delta(existingState, newState);

        assertEquals(delta.additions, Set.of(0, 99, 11));
        assertEquals(delta.subtractions, Set.of(1, 4));
    }

    
    @Test
    void testSame()
    {
        Set<Integer> existingState = Set.of(1,2);
        Set<Integer> newState = Set.of(1,2);

        var delta = Sets.delta(existingState, newState);

        assertEquals(delta.additions, Set.of());
        assertEquals(delta.subtractions, Set.of());
    }
    
    @Test
    void testBothEmpty()
    {
        Set<Integer> existingState = Set.of();
        Set<Integer> newState = Set.of();

        var delta = Sets.delta(existingState, newState);

        assertEquals(delta.additions, Set.of());
        assertEquals(delta.subtractions, Set.of());
    }
    
    @Test
    void testAddOne()
    {
        Set<Integer> existingState = Set.of();
        Set<Integer> newState = Set.of(1);

        var delta = Sets.delta(existingState, newState);

        assertEquals(delta.additions, Set.of(1));
        assertEquals(delta.subtractions, Set.of());
    }
    
    @Test
    void testRemoveOne()
    {
        Set<Integer> existingState = Set.of(1);
        Set<Integer> newState = Set.of();

        var delta = Sets.delta(existingState, newState);

        assertEquals(delta.additions, Set.of());
        assertEquals(delta.subtractions, Set.of(1));
    }
    
    @Test
    void testAddOneRemoveOne()
    {
        Set<Integer> existingState = Set.of(1);
        Set<Integer> newState = Set.of(0);

        var delta = Sets.delta(existingState, newState);

        assertEquals(delta.additions, Set.of(0));
        assertEquals(delta.subtractions, Set.of(1));
    }

}
```