# Comparing 2 sets of Java

Tags: java, list, set

I have 2 Hash Sets, both containing x amount of "Names" (Object). What **I would like to do is find out if my *"Names"* in *Names1* or in *Names2*** ?

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {

 Set<Name> Names1 = new HashSet<Name>();
    Names1.add(new Name("Jon"));
    Names1.add(new Name("Mark"));
    Names1.add(new Name("Mike"));
    Names1.add(new Name("Helen"));
    Set<Name> Names2 = new HashSet<Name>();
    Names2.add(new Name("Mark"));
    Names2.add(new Name("Mike"));
    Names2.add(new Name("Sally"));



    Set<Name> listCommon = new HashSet<Name>(); 

    for (Name element : Names1) {
        if (!Names2.contains(element)) {
            listCommon.add(element);
        }
    }

    for (Name element : listCommon) {
        System.out.println(element.getNameString());
    }

}
public class Name {
String ord;

Name(String ord1){
    ord = ord1;
}

public String getNameString(){
    return ord;
}
}
```

So when I ran this code, I got no output at all, cause the

```
'if (!Names2.contains(element)) {'
```

never occurred. But what I would like to get as output would be *Jon* and *Helen*. Since they are not in *Names2*.

Comment: remove your ! operator to compute common names.

Comment: Are the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your `Name` class removed for brevity or genuinely absent?

Comment: You need to override `equals` and `hashCode` method from super class  which would be the `Object` class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the difference between two sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644579/getting-the-difference-between-two-sets)

Comment: Surely if OP hasn't overridden equals and hashcode, then *all* elements in `Names1` would be added to `listCommon`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `equals` and `hashCode` methods overriden in `Name` class, you can use `retainAll` method of `Set` (javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection))) to find out common elements. E.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Set<Name> Names1 = new HashSet<Name>();
    Names1.add(new Name("Jon"));
    Names1.add(new Name("Mark"));
    Names1.add(new Name("Mike"));
    Names1.add(new Name("Helen"));
    Set<Name> Names2 = new HashSet<Name>();
    Names2.add(new Name("Mark"));
    Names2.add(new Name("Mike"));
    Names2.add(new Name("Sally"));

    Names1.retainAll(Names2);

    for(Name name : Names1){
        System.out.println(name.getName());
    }
}
```

Here's example Name class with `equals` and `hashCode` methods:

```
class Name{
    private String name;

    public Name(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return null != name ? name.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return o instanceof Name
                && ((Name)o).name != null
                && this.name != null
                && ((Name)o).name.equals(this.name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Please note that `retainAll` method modifies the `set` it's being called on (Names1 in our case). If you want to preserve the original set then you can copy the elements in another set and call `retainAll` on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Set::contains` check will not work, because you failed to override `Object::equals`. The default implementation of `Object::equals` is checking for reference equality (==), meaning the Name must be the exact same instance to be considered equal.

As others have stated, the correct thing for you to do would be to implement hashCode and equals in your Name class.

Failing that, you would have to iterate through the set and test `obj1.getNameString().equals(obj2.getNameString())` to do your own hand-coded and inefficient version of the `Set::contains` test.