# How to get the difference of two maps based on the key set?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, set-difference

I have two maps:

```
Map<String, Sample> newMap = convertJSONObjectToSampleMap(newMapStr);
Map<String, Sample> oldMap = convertJSONObjectToSampleMap(oldMapStr);
```

*the `Sample` is some custom class*

The  `newMap` has keys: `[1,2,3,4,5]`
The  `oldMap` has keys: `[2,3,4,5,8]`

**What is the best way to get difference between them, .e, get `Sample`s with keys: `1` and `8`?**

I thought to use `Collections` and extract `Set<>`:

```
Set<String> newSet = newMap.keySet();
Set<String> oldSet = oldMap.keySet();
```

Thank you,

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064570/what-is-the-best-way-get-the-symmetric-difference-between-two-sets-in-java

Answer (score 6):

What you want is called the symmetric difference.

[image]

Guava provides such a method.

```
Set<String> diff = Sets.symmetricDifference(newSet, oldSet);
```

Then just iterate through the set get the samples.

```
List<Sample> samples = new ArrayList<>();
for(String key : diff){
    if(oldMap.containsKey(key)){
        samples.add(oldMap.get(key));
    } else {
        samples.add(newMap.get(key));
    }
}
```

You can also do it with the official API, basically the symmetric difference is the union minus the intersection of both sets, but why reinvent the wheel?

Using an external dependency can be bad if you're using only one method, but Guava provides a lot of useful features that are a must.

Comment: -1 This answer introduces an external dependancy on your project.

Comment: @ErickRobertson Surely you can do it with the official JDK, but Guava is really a must and I don't see any reasons for not using an external library for this sort of things.

Comment: The question is how to obtain a the `values` of the map, not only the `keys`, you need to add a step to obtain these keys.

Comment: @AVolpe You're right, fixed.

Comment: It's not gaining you anything here.  You still have to have a loop around a `containsKey` in your code, and it's less efficient. I disagree that "Guava is really a must."

Answer (score 2):

**Loop through one map and compare.**

It's only `O(n)` to loop through one of the maps.  Consider this code:

```
for (String key: oldMap.keySet()) {
    if (newMap.containsKey(key))
        newMap.remove(key);
    else
        newMap.put(key, oldMap.get(key));
}
```

And the `newMap` will now contain only the unique entries from both sets.  It gives you the keys and the values, so all the data is in one place.  It's fast, because you only need to loop through the keys in one of the maps and you don't have to create sets.

Comment: `newMap.keySet().removeAll(oldMap.keySet())` I guess this is significantly simpler, isn't it?

Comment: @allprog then you would have keys from `newMap` not found in `oldMap`, but you won't have the keys that are only in `oldMap`.

Comment: Ah, Ok. I didn't consider the `else` branch.

Answer (score 2):

Use a function like this if you're interested only on the keys:

```
public static Set<String> getDiff(Map<String,Object> mapA, Map<String,Object> mapB) {
    Set<String> diff = mapA.keySet();
    for (String s: mapB.keySet()) {
        if (diff.contains(s))
            diff.remove(s);
        else
            diff.add(s);
    }
    return diff;
}
```

Use the following function for the full diff Map (without affecting your existing Map objects):

```
public static Map<String,Object> getDiff(Map<String,Object> mapA, Map<String,Object> mapB) {
   Map<String,Object> diff = new HashMap<String,Object>();
   diff.putAll(mapA);
   for (String s: mapB.keySet()) {
       if (diff.containsKey(s))
           diff.remove(s);
       else
           diff.put(s, mapB.get(s));
   }
   return diff;
}
```