# How to do set operations on sorted lists in Kotlin or Java?

Tags: java, kotlin, guava

I have two sorted lists of unique items and I want to find their set difference and set intersection in a fast and cache-friendly way, such as with the **C++** [std::set_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference) and [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection).

However, now I am working in **Kotlin** and I cannot find the corresponding functionality. Since the Kotlin standard library is build on top of the Java standard library, a **Java** answer is welcome.

I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644579/getting-the-difference-between-two-sets) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064570/what-is-the-best-way-get-the-symmetric-difference-between-two-sets-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1) great questions and all the answers, but as far as I see, **they deal only with arbitrary sets, thus fortfeiting the sortedness**.

The same goes for [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained).

Comment: Removing the C++ tag as this isn't actually about C++ code.

Comment: How about using a `TreeSet` to achieve sorting?

Comment: Are both sorted lists contain unique items?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya That is certainly possible, but it has worse complexity and worse cache locality than just using lists. Check out the C++ links I posted.

Comment: @Maxim Yes, that is the case

Comment: @MartinDrozdik  May I know the datatype of items?

Comment: I don't think there is any built-in methods for this kind of operations in the Java library, not sure about Guava though.

Comment: Just a nit-pick: your assertion that "the Kotlin standard library is built on top of the Java standard library" is valid only for the Kotlin JVM variant. It's not true for Kotlin Native (or Kotlin JS).

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Let's say `Double`, but it shouldn't really matter. @DodgyCodeException Thanks! Didn't know that.

Comment: Another minor point: in C++ you have true cache locality when the data is stored by value in each element. But in Java, if the type is `Double`, that's a wrapper object with the actual `double` data being scattered all over the heap.

Comment: Very specific task. Think you should create methods by your own. C++ implementation is simple and use a kind of merge sort but without sorting. In Java there is `retainAll()` method to find intersection, but it complexity is O(n*m) as the fact that both arrays are sorted not used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the merge-intersect implementation which runs O(n+m) in worst-case scenario

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> intersect(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    final int size1 = list1.size();
    final int size2 = list2.size();
    final List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(Math.min(size1, size2));

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < size1 && j < size2) {
        T a = list1.get(i);
        int compare = a.compareTo(list2.get(j));
        if (compare < 0)
            i++;
        else if (compare > 0)
            j++;
        else {
            result.add(a);
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but if the two lists contain millions of elements, but only two elements in common between them, then you'd be badly over-allocating the result list. You might want to do `if (result.capacity() > result.size() * 2) result.trimToSize();` or just let the ArrayList implementation do appropriate resizing by not using an initial capacity.