# How to find lines that are not similar when comparing two texts

Tags: java

I have a list that contains elements of different texts such that:

First element `txt1` is the following text:

```
Analysis of coverage
Better algorithm
Strategy of random search
```

Second element `txt2` is the following text:

```
Analysis of coverage
Better algorithm
Master process
Strategy of genetic search
```

Third element `txt3` is the following text:

```
Analysis of coverage
Better algorithm
Master process
Strategy of genetic search
```

What I want is to compare each element with the previous one and detect any differences. In the case above, I want to compare `txt1` with `txt2` and return the following lines as they are different:

```
Master process
Strategy of genetic search
```

But when comparing `txt2` and `txt3`, there is no difference at all.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way get the symmetric difference between two sets in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064570/what-is-the-best-way-get-the-symmetric-difference-between-two-sets-in-java)

Comment: if (!set.add){...}

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: Don't want to give you specific code as currently question shows no attempt at the problem.

I would try this:

1. Read contents of elements from the list and convert into single string.
2. Separate String contents by newline `String.split("\\r?\\n")`. Essentially, you want to have a list of sentences present in each element. If needed, you can also trim each sentence of white spaces: `String.split("\\s*\\r?\\n\\s*")`.
3. Compare the two lists and retrieve difference. There's many ways you can do that e.g: iterate between both lists and record difference, or use `ArrayList.removeAll()` (i.e. you remove all contents of one list from another list and see the change). Good luck!