# Find the symmetric difference between two sets in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections, set

Is there a Kotlin stdlib function to find the symmetric difference between two sets? So given two sets `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 3, 5]` the symmetric difference would be `[2, 5]`.

I've written this extension function which works fine, but it feels like an operation that should already exist within the collections framework.

```
fun <T> Set<T>.symmetricDifference(other: Set<T>): Set<T> {
    val mine = this subtract other
    val theirs = other subtract this
    return mine union theirs
}
```

EDIT: [What is the best way get the symmetric difference between two sets in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064570/what-is-the-best-way-get-the-symmetric-difference-between-two-sets-in-java) suggests Guava or ApacheCommons, but I'm wondering if Kotlin's stdlib supports this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way get the symmetric difference between two sets in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064570/what-is-the-best-way-get-the-symmetric-difference-between-two-sets-in-java). You can use java libraries in kotlin, I don't think there is anything embedded in the language to do that. The reason you probably aren't finding anything is because `difference` and `symetric difference` are 2 different things, and you are searching for the wrong one.

Comment: @Alex.T thanks for the suggestion - "symmetric difference" is what I'm looking for. The link was helpful, but all of the solutions use Guava or ApacheCommons or a custom implementation. So it looks like Java doesn't support this in its standard library, and I'm not seeing anything in Kotlin either...

Comment: Most frameworks will avoid providing special helpers for things that are easy enough to build out of more general functions.

Comment: @LouisWasserman sure, this just seems like a function that would be just as useful as union, intersect, subtract, all of which are provided, so I thought I may have been overlooking it in the docs

Answer (score 3):

Minor variation:

```
infix fun <T> Set<T>.xor(that: Set<T>): Set<T> = (this - that) + (that - this)
```

Usage:

```
a xor b
```

To reduce GC overhead a more complex [Guava-like](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/46be346721fcdc1a805850799ee549fcd173cf99/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java#L961) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064570/what-is-the-best-way-get-the-symmetric-difference-between-two-sets-in-java/8064621#8064621) with a custom iterator would have to be used.

Comment: You are the MOTHER!